# D3.js substitute text in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, text, d3.js, buttonclick

I was wondering if I could create a D3 function that selects a paragraph, removes the text in it and appends some new text.
If so, what would be the best approach to do this?

I tried something like

```
    d3.select("#triggerButton")
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.select("#myParagraph")
      .remove()
      .append("p")
      .attr("id", "myNewParagrap")
      .select("#myNewParagrap")
      .append("text")
      .text("This is my new text")
  })
```

This doesn't work as it only deletes the original paragraph without creating a new one.
I tried to create a second 'on-click' event for the same #trigger, but this resulted in the 'remove event' not happening and the new text being attached to the end of the body, while I would like it to be on top as the original paragraph was.
Is there a more elegant approach to this problem?

Moreover, can I include in the new paragraph hyperlinks or words that toggle an event (for example a tooltip that appreas on mouseover and disappears on mouseout)?

Comment: Have a parent element (e.g. a `div`) contain the paragraph you want to remove. Then you can remove it and add another paragraph in the same place.

Comment: d3.select("#triggerButton")
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.select("#myParagraph")
      .remove()
      .append("p")
      .attr("id", "myNewParagrap")
      .select("#myNewParagrap")
      .append("text")
      .text("This is my new text")
       })

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your paragraph element in a div and then add and remove the paragraph from that div element. See the working [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/W6624XZPRQ72mPjVdhgS?p=preview). Hope it helps.

```
function removeDiv() {
      d3.select("#removablediv").remove();
      d3.select(".example")
        .append("p")
        .attr("id", "myNewParagrap")
        .append("text")
        .text("This is my new text")
     }
```